# Meteor: accounts-ui how - to change config?

Tags: facebook, node.js, meteor, config

I'm new to node and Meteor
I've set up simple log in flow with Meteor and accounts-ui package, coupled with accounts-facebook, but I've entered wrong Facebook OAuth data in the setup pop-up. How can I change the parameters that the package uses for communicating with Facebook (that is, app secret, redirect_uri etc?)

Answer (score 8):

First run:

```
$ meteor reset
```

within your project root so that you clean up your current development mongodb. Otherwise, you can just connect to your mongodb instance using

```
$ meteor mongo
```

and manually find/delete/update your facebook app oauth credentials.

```
$ meteor:PRIMARY> db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.find()
$ meteor:PRIMARY> db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.remove()
```

In a javascript file that is within the `server` directory:

```
if (ServiceConfiguration.configurations.find({service: 'facebook'}).count()===0) {
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: "facebook",
    appId: "app-id-you-get-from-facebook",
    secret: "app-secret-you-get-from-facebook"
  });
}

// bonus: get some additional profile info from facebook and cache on the user document
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user) {
  check(options, Object);
  check(user, Object);

  options.profile.email = user.services.facebook.email;
  options.profile.facebookId = user.services.facebook.id;

  user.profile = options.profile;

  return user;
});
```

Comment: You can also use MongoVUE and connect to localhost port 3001 (given that you used 3000 default for meteor) and make changes in the GUI...

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice)

you can do like this

```
// first, remove configuration entry in case service is already configured
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: "weibo"
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
  service: "weibo",
  clientId: "1292962797",
  secret: "75a730b58f5691de5522789070c319bc"
});
```

For facebook,i think we have `appId` and `secretId`

I don't know whether we can change redirect url or not using this,may be not

Comment: Can you please tell me where do I run these commands? From a script file, or directly from console?

Comment: The code would go on the server, somewhere between if (Meteor.isServer) { //HERE } or in a a .js file in a server/ directory

Comment: Thank you. Where can I check which accounts-facebook attributes are configurable?

Comment: I don't know,I'm too new to meteor

Comment: @KubaOrlik, If you reset the database you can configure from starting

Comment: I know, but isn't it a little bit to drastic? It will flush ALL the config, right? And I want only to change two parameters

Comment: what are the other params you want to change?

Comment: None, I'm just interested in a way to change the `appId` and `secretId` parameters of the accounts-ui package

Comment: Okay,i think there is no way to change `redirect url` through meteor,if you want to really change it u need to change it in facebook site only,we can change only `appId` and `secretId` using meteor